# Data frames of unequal lengths and joins based on shared variable and range of shared variable

Tags: r

I need to add a column to my original data frame, `df1`, based on where the `Value` variable in `df1` falls relative to observed values in `df2`.  My attempt so far has been to use `left_join` but since `df1` and `df2` are not of equal lengths this has not worked out well as `df1` ends up with additional rows due to the unequal lengths.

Think of `df2` as standings in a contest where the `Value` and `Amount` columns are ranked from highest to lowest.  For example, the value returned for row 2 in `df1` should be 200 because the `Value` of 450 in `df1` is more than the `Value` of 400 (lowest range) but less than the value of 525 (highest range) in `df2`.  Each `Value` variable from `df1` should be evaluated against the range it falls in (lowest and highest) and then return the appropriate `Amount`.  When ties exist, the tied `Amount` should be returned.  For example, row 3 in `df1` with a `Value` of 525 should return `Amount` of 500 because it's tied with `Value` of 525 in `df2`.

```
df1:
        Date Value
1  10/1/2021   500
2  10/1/2021   450
3  10/1/2021   525
4  10/1/2021   700
5  10/1/2021   250
6  10/1/2021   105
7  10/1/2021    90
8  10/1/2021   325
9  10/1/2021   300
10 10/1/2021   275
11 10/1/2021   100
12 10/1/2021   289
13 10/1/2021   230
14 10/1/2021    50

df2:
        Date Rk Value Amount
1  10/1/2021  1   600    700
2  10/1/2021  2   525    500
3  10/1/2021  3   400    200
4  10/1/2021  4   350    100
5  10/1/2021  5   325     75
6  10/1/2021  6   300     65
7  10/1/2021  7   250     55
8  10/1/2021  8   200     50
9  10/1/2021  9   150     40
10 10/1/2021 10   100     30

desired output:
        Date Value Amount
1  10/1/2021   500    200
2  10/1/2021   450    200
3  10/1/2021   525    500
4  10/1/2021   700    700
5  10/1/2021   250     55
6  10/1/2021   105     30
7  10/1/2021    90      0
8  10/1/2021   325     75
9  10/1/2021   300     65
10 10/1/2021   275     55
11 10/1/2021   100     30
12 10/1/2021   289     55
13 10/1/2021   230     50
14 10/1/2021    50      0


## original df
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"10/1/2021"), Value = c(500L, 450L, 525L, 700L, 250L, 105L, 90L, 
325L, 300L, 275L, 100L, 289L, 230L, 50L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))

## df with Amount variable
df2 <- structure(list(Date = c("10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"10/1/2021", "10/1/2021"), Rk = 1:10, Value = c(600L, 525L, 400L, 
350L, 325L, 300L, 250L, 200L, 150L, 100L), Amount = c(700L, 500L, 
200L, 100L, 75L, 65L, 55L, 50L, 40L, 30L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

## desired output
desired <- structure(list(Date = c("10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"10/1/2021"), Value = c(500L, 450L, 525L, 700L, 250L, 105L, 90L, 
325L, 300L, 275L, 100L, 289L, 230L, 50L), Amount = c(200L, 200L, 
500L, 700L, 55L, 30L, 0L, 75L, 65L, 55L, 30L, 55L, 50L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below is a base R code:

```
df1$Amount <- cut(df1$Value, c(rev(df2$Value), Inf),rev(df2$Amount), right = FALSE)
df1$Amount <- as.numeric(as.character(df1$Amount))
df1$Amount[is.na(df1$Amount)] <- 0
df1
        Date Value Amount
1  10/1/2021   500    200
2  10/1/2021   450    200
3  10/1/2021   525    500
4  10/1/2021   700    700
5  10/1/2021   250     55
6  10/1/2021   105     30
7  10/1/2021    90      0
8  10/1/2021   325     75
9  10/1/2021   300     65
10 10/1/2021   275     55
11 10/1/2021   100     30
12 10/1/2021   289     55
13 10/1/2021   230     50
14 10/1/2021    50      0
```

Comment: any suggestions on how to deal with the fact that my `df$Value` doesn't like `cut` because not enough unique values? I tried using `.bincode` instead of `cut` to bypass this error but it did not mutate the correct `Amount` in my real world data.

Comment: @On_an_island what exactly do you mean by not having enough unique values? You can have even 5 of them. As long as they are sorted.

Comment: I meant that there are not enough unique breaks in my real world `df1$Value`, something that `cut` will throw an error for: `Error: Problem with mutate() input Amount.
x 'breaks' are not unique`

Comment: @On_an_island there is nothing like *not enough*. Do you mean you have duplicates? Because cut will work even with only 2 breaks

Comment: @On_an_island also note that `df1$Values` need not be unique. on the other hand `df2$Values` need to be sorted in ascending order and unique. The error you are obtaining for `breaks not unique` is probably because you are using `df1$Values` instead of `df2$Values` check my code again

Comment: that is correct. My real world data contains duplicate values in `df1$Value`; sorry for the confusion and misuse of terminology. But I thought that using `.bincode` as suggested in other posts instead of `cut` would be a way to get around it but that is not pulling in the correct `Amount`.

Comment: @On_an_island it doesn't matter that `df1$Values` have duplicates. They are not part of the breakes. They are to be broken into groups. Check the code again. I am not using df1$Values as the breaks but rather df2$Values

Comment: you are correct. The error is because `df2$Value` has duplicates.  With your suggest code requiring `df2$Value` to be unique, do you have any suggestions on how to handle this when `df2$Value` contain duplicates? Real world data doesn't fit nicely with pretend data used for SO post purposes.

Comment: @On_an_island how can you have duplicates on df2$Values? Why do you have duplicates? Do the duplicates have the same df2$Amount? or is the Amount different? Now that is a whole different question that needs further clarification. If they are duplicates you cannot tell where for example 450 lies. Is it the first 400, or the duplicated 400?. And then which amount to take? for the first or the duplicated? This causes alot of problems. Any thing that takes range must be UNIQUE. so make your data unique

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238783/discussion-between-on-an-island-and-onyambu).

Comment: I'm accepting your response as provided as it works well for my data. The issue with the `breaks not unique` on `df2$Value` is easily solved by removing duplicates in `df2`. By doing so, I'm not losing any information that I need since the distinct copy of the duplicate contains the value I need added in `df1`. Thank you.